# Analytics reporting all subdomains but not the main domain

Tags: google-analytics

My main domain is say example.com. Now I have a dozen subdomains and I have created Views for each subdomain with this filter:  "Include only > traffic to the hostname > that contain"

So for the subdomain -  abc.example.com  -  the filter will be:-

Include only > traffic to the hostname > that contain = abc.example.com

The reporting is okay for the subdomains, but for the main domain the reporting is always a blank no matter how many times a billion people visit it. I know it is tracking because you can see even tools.pingdom.com showing the js code.

These are the filters i have used for the main domain:

1. Include only > traffic to the hostname > that beging with = example.com
2. Include only > traffic to the hostname > that beging with = www.example.com

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain one non-filtered view, it's a good practice.

To filter only main domain (suggested profile name: Example.com - Main) use:

custom filter -> include -> filter pattern: (www.|^)example.com

More about filtering subdomains: http://www.wearefine.com/mingle/filtering-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

---

**Why you can't do that in the way that you did?**

It's logic error. Simply your domain can't begins with www.example.com AND example.com in the same time :)